# Web api authentication and MVC 4

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following solution:

1. Web api project.
2. MVC 4 project.

I need to authenticate user by sending its credentials using a JSON request (https is a must).
 is it a good approach ? and how can i authenticate the user on both web api and MVC .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it a good approach ?

Yeah, why not.

> and how can i authenticate the user on both web api and MVC .

If the Web API requires authentication you could use the same Forms Authentication as the MVC application. So you could configure Forms Authentication in the web.config of the Web API application and then decorate the actions that require authentication with the `[Authorize]` attribute. Then clients that need to query those methods will need to include the Forms Authentication cookie along with the request.

It is important to note that in order for the Web API to be able to decrypt the forms authentication cookie that was emitted the MVC application, both applications need to share the same [`machine keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx#paght000007_machinekeyexplained).

Comment: so what you mean is that i need to do form authentication on both MVC and web api?

Comment: That's one way to share the same authentication between the 2 applications. If that's not what you are trying to achieve then please explain your precise goal.

Comment: That's what i want, can you provide a sample? i google it alot and couldn't find a complete example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may already start by setting what I suggested you in my answer and see how it goes. You need to configure forms authentication for both applications and then decorate protected actions with the Authorize attribute. Then when you need to send a request to the Web API you need to include the forms authentication cookie along with the request. If you have some troubles implementing this, don't hesitate to show your code and the progress you've made so far so that we could help you.

Comment: My Web API is ignoring my Authentication attribute. That is, some times when I make a call, and I am authenticated, it treats me as unauthenticated, and other times, I will be unauthenticated and it still treats me as authenticated. I see that the is an authentication attribute in system.web.http and system.web.mvc, do I ignore the one in system.web.http? Both Web API and MVC are part of the same project, and server deploy.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm trying this approach with MVC 5/Web API 2. The default config of Web API 2 calls SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication() which prevents this approach from working. According to [this article](http://bit.ly/Zf7QKy), removing this call makes the API vulnerable to CSRF attacks. Is there a way to make this work without the security risk?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I created a Custom Authorization filter inheriting from AuthorizeAttribute. Now when the url hits api/Account/Login how should I validate user and the use IPrincipal concept ? Any comment or link will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Basic Authentication. You need to create  Authenticationfilter.

There is an opensource library. (WEbAPIDoddle)

https://github.com/WebAPIDoodle/WebAPIDoodle