# MVC application calling Web API application needing same user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

If I have an MVC application that has an authenticated user, and either from client-side JavaScript, or from an MVC controller, I wish to call a Web API that is in a different project to the MVC application, but use the same user credentials.

How would I go about this?

I am using the latest in VS2013 - MVC 5 with Web API 2. Currently to authenticate I am using forms auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link to solve your problem

Works fine for me

[Web api authentication and MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052176/web-api-authentication-and-mvc-4)

Comment: How do I send the forms auth cookie to the web api?

Comment: You need to configure your applications to share the authentication cookie [see](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx). This as well as the proposed solution above assumes that the both projects (web sites) are on the same server (machine).